# DNS IP address auto reset

Tags: dns, ip, backdoor

I have a unofficial Windows and i noticed that my internet connection gets reset.
By taking a closer look at it, i found that the DNS server address is set to an IP in China.
Any reason why this wouldn't be the sign of some backdoor ?

Comment: Cracked Windows distributions are notorious sources of malware. Wipe the disk and install Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is set to an IP in China. Any reason why this wouldn't be the sign of some backdoor ?

If you are located in China then this would be probably fine.
If you are located elsewhere then it might be a backdoor or some [malware like DNSChanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSChanger).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a unofficial Windows

Such "unofficial" MS Windows versions were known to have been tempered with and indeed include extra functionality.